# ElasticSearch query optimization - Java API

Tags: java, elasticsearch, query-optimization, wildcard

I am newbie to ES and am searching on a record set of 100k data.
Here is my mapping and setting JSON with which i have indexed my data:

setings.json

```
{
    "index": {
        "analysis": {
            "tokenizer": {
                "ngram_tokenizer": {
                    "type": "ngram",
                    "min_gram": 3,
                    "max_gram": 10
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "ngram_tokenizer_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "ngram_tokenizer"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

mappings.json

```
{
    "product": {
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type": "string",
                "analyzer": "ngram_tokenizer_analyzer",
                "store": true
            },
            "description": {
                "type": "string",
                "analyzer": "ngram_tokenizer_analyzer",
                "store": true
            },
            "vendorModelNumber": {
                "type": "string",
                "analyzer": "ngram_tokenizer_analyzer",
                "store": true
            },
            "brand": {
                "type": "string",
                "analyzer": "ngram_tokenizer_analyzer",
                "store": true
            },
            "specifications": {
                "type": "string",
                "analyzer": "ngram_tokenizer_analyzer",
                "store": true
            },
            "upc": {
                "type": "string",
                "analyzer": "ngram_tokenizer_analyzer",
                "store": true
            },
            "storeSkuId": {
                "type": "string",
                "analyzer": "ngram_tokenizer_analyzer",
                "store": true
            },
            "modelNumber": {
                "type": "string",
                "analyzer": "ngram_tokenizer_analyzer",
                "store": true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to query documents based on all the fields mentioned according to some priority. Here is my query to search for all the records.

```
BoolQueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
int boost = 7;

for (String str : dataSplit) {
    query.should(QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery("name", "*" + str.toLowerCase() + "*").boost(boost));
}
boost--;
for (String str : dataSplit) {
    query.should(QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery("description", "*" + str.toLowerCase() + "*").boost(boost));
}
boost--;
for (String str : dataSplit) {
    query.should(QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery("modelNumber", "*" + str.toLowerCase() + "*").boost(boost));
}
boost--;
for (String str : dataSplit) {
    query.should(QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery("vendorModelNumber", "*" + str.toLowerCase() + "*").boost(boost));
}
boost--;
for (String str : dataSplit) {
    query.should(QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery("storeSkuId", "*" + str.toLowerCase() + "*").boost(boost));
}
boost--;
for (String str : dataSplit) {
    query.should(QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery("upc", "*" + str.toLowerCase() + "*").boost(boost));
}
boost--;
for (String str : dataSplit) {
    query.should(QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery("brand", "*" + str.toLowerCase() + "*").boost(boost));
}
client.prepareSearch(index).setQuery(query).setSize(200).setExplain(true).execute().actionGet();
```

The query does help me in searching data and works fine but my issue is that it takes a lot of time since I am using wildcard query. 
Can someone please help in optimising this query or guide me in finding the best-suited query for my search?
TIA.

Comment: Why do you use wildcard queries in the first place? Having an ngram tokenizer with 3+, a normal match query should work with inputs longer than 2 characters. Or what is the reason for the ngram tokenizer anyway? A sidenote; with this analyzer (as defined) your queries will be case sensitive. Possibly intended, but quite unusual.

Comment: Thanks @Slomo you are right. I shouldnt have used wildcards with ngram. can i make it case insensitive? and with ngram i should be querying with term query or match which is the more optimal way? sorry if that is not a sensible question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, let me answer the simple question first: handle case sensitivity. If you define a custom analyzer, you can add different filters, which are applied to each token **after** the input has been processed by the tokenizer.

```
{
"index": {
    "analysis": {
        "tokenizer": {
            "ngram_tokenizer": {
                "type": "ngram",
                "min_gram": 3,
                "max_gram": 10
            }
        },
        "analyzer": {
            "ngram_tokenizer_analyzer": {
                "type": "custom",
                "tokenizer": "ngram_tokenizer",
                "filter": [
                    "lowercase",
                    ...
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you see, there is an existing *lowercase* filter, which will simply transform all tokens to lower case. I strongly recommend referring to the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-tokenfilters.html). There are a *lot* of these token filters.

---

Now the more complicated part: NGram tokenizers. Again, for deeper understanding, you might want to read [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html). But referring to your problem, your tokenizer will essentially create terms of length 3 to 10. Which means the text

```
I am an example TEXT.
```

Will basically create a lot of tokens. Just to show a few:

- Size 3: "I a", " am", "am ", ..., "TEX", "EXT"
- Size 4: "I am", " am ", "am a", ..., " TEX", "TEXT".
- Size 10: "I am an ex", ...

You get the idea. (The *lowercase* token filter would lowercase these tokens now)

Difference between Match and Term Query: Match queries are analyzed, while term queries are not. In fact, that means your match queries can match multiple terms. Example: you match `exam"`.

This would match 3 terms in fact: `exa`, `xam` and `exam`.

This has influence on the score of the matches. The more matches, the higher the score. In some cases it's desired, in other cases not.

A term query is not analyzed, which means `exam` would match, but only one term (`exam` of course). However, since it's not analyzed, it's also not lowercased, meaning you have to do that in code yourself. `Exam` would never match, because there is no term with capital letters in your index, if you use the lowercase tokenfilter.

Not sure about your use-case. But I have a feeling, that you could (or even want) indeed use the term query. **But** be aware, there are **no** terms in your index with a size bigger than 10. Because that's what your ngram-tokenizer does.

/ EDIT:

Something worth pointing out regarding match queries, and the reason why you might want to use terms: Some match queries like `Simple` will also match `mple` from `example`.

Comment: tnx a lot @Slomo for the detailed explanation. will refine my code an dwill go through the doc as well. :)

Comment: so suppose I need to search multiple values on multiple fields, bool with match query would be a good option right?

Comment: @DivyaMenon You can. Or maybe you can also use the [multiMatch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) where you should also be able to weight fields. Maybe a concrete query example with expected results would help to answer your question.